# Disabling Rails' layout depending on contents of params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to have Rails automatically disable layouts depending on whether `params[:layout]` is true or false, rather than having to specify `render :show, :layout => params[:layout]` after every action?

Answer (score 2):

Try either one. Let me know which one worked for you.

```
class ThingssController < ApplicationController
  layout params[:layout]

  ...
end
```

or

```
class ThingssController < ApplicationController
  layout :layouting

  ...

  private

    def layouting
      params[:layout] == true 
    end
end
```

Comment: The first one won’t work because `layout params[:layout]` will be evaluated when the controller is first loaded, not when the request comes in.

Comment: The second one seems like it’ll work, but I’m curious about how `params[:layout]` is even being set. Is it an AJAX request or something? Controlling layout-rendering with a URL parameter seems questionable to me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 

I don't know how he sets value for `params[:layout]`. He might have a hidden field in some forms that set `params[:layout]` to be true.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn’t expecting you to know that, maybe it should have been a comment on the question instead.

Comment: Second gives: `Your layout method :determine_layout returned true. It should have returned a String, false, or nil`.

Answer (score 1):

how about adding a after_filter

```
class ThingssController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :get_layout

...

  def get_layout
    render :layout => false unless params[:layout] == true
  end
end
```

Comment: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note...`

Comment: its probably because of the respond_to do |format| ... end block. Try removing that.

Comment: There is no `respond_to` block in the controller action.